# How to remove a layout in another layout, when a button pressed

Tags: android

My clickFunc method shows a table layout when b1 button is pressed. And after pressed, the table is shown correctly. First onclick is working correctly but I couldnt remove the table when I press second time which call the second onclick? How can I remove the table when I press the button second time?

```
public void clickFunc(){
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch (v.getId())
                    {case (R.id.b1):{
                        b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        view2=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yorumm, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tablely), true);

                     break;}

                    default:{}}}});

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch (v.getId())
                    {case (R.id.b2):{
                                        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        break;}

                    default:{}}}});

    }
```

Comment: where is the code that changes the layout ?

Comment: Also, you have two buttons. not one, please edit you answer. And why you inflate the layout and not use findviewbyid?

Comment: What did you mention? xml file or java code? In this code view2 variable add the table into the layout. I just want to remove that view2 actually. What is needed more in here? If there is need xml file I can put here.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer so you can close the question

Comment: ahh sorry. I will answer with the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Here is the working code:

```
        public void clickFunc(){
    mvisib =(Button)findViewById(R.id.mvisible);
    minvisib =(Button) findViewById(R.id.minvisible);
    final View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yorumm, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yorummm), true);
    editViews();
    getComments();
    comment();
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mvisib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId())   // v is the button that was clicked
                {case (R.id.mvisible):{
                    mvisib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    minvisib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 break;}

                default:{}}}});

    minvisib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
             switch (v1.getId())   // v is the button that was clicked
                {case (R.id.minvisible):{
                                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    minvisib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    mvisib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    break;}

                default:{}}}});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this - 
get the outer layout from which you want to remove. for example-

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.outer);
```

//get the view to remove

```
TableLayout tb=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
```

//remove the view

```
ll.removeView(tb);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it didnt work or I didnt apply correctly. I solve my question with visiblity with GONE. I share the solution in edit section on above.